# VBA Insert Row to bottom of specific table and shift all cells down

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I have a spreadsheet with multiple tabs and multiple tables on each tab. I want to add a button that adds a row to the bottom of a table and shifts the worksheet down so that the table doesn't run into the tables below.
I have used a generic code found somewhere else on stack to add a row and then assigned it to a button, and it worked beautifully, but want to include a function to add a row to the whole sheet below the table. What do I add to the code to shift the sheet down? Thanks in advance!

````
Private Sub InsertRowsInTable(ByVal targetTableName As String)
    
    ' Ask user how many rows to ask
    Dim rowsToAdd As Variant
    rowsToAdd = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows", 1)
    
    ' If user didn't input anything, default to 1
    If rowsToAdd = vbNullString Then rowsToAdd = 1
    
    Dim targetTable As ListObject
    Set targetTable = Range(targetTableName).ListObject
    
    ' Resize the table to add rows
    targetTable.Resize targetTable.Range.Resize(targetTable.Range.Rows.Count + rowsToAdd)
        
End Sub```
````

Comment: Hi. Tables have a method to add a row (at the bottom by default) of the table that will shift all cells below the table down. Try `targetTable.ListRows.Add` See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.listrows and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listrows.add

Comment: Use the `AlwaysInsert` parameter to choose if you want the cells always shifted or shifted only if there cells below are not blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your responses!

I solved it with a combination of Elio Fernandes and Vincent G's suggestion.

I added `For rowinsert = 0 To rowsToAdd - 1` when resizing my table. So what I ended up with was

```
Private Sub InsertRowsInTable(ByVal targetTableName As String)
   
    ' Ask user how many rows to ask
    Dim rowsToAdd As Variant
    rowsToAdd = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows", 1)
   
    ' If user didn't input anything, default to 1
    If rowsToAdd = vbNullString Then rowsToAdd = 1
   
    Dim targetTable As ListObject
    Set targetTable = Range(targetTableName).ListObject
   
    Dim rowinsert As Integer
   
    ' Resize the table to add rows
    For rowinsert = 0 To rowsToAdd - 1
        targetTable.Range.EntireRow(targetTable.Range.Rows.Count + 1).Insert
    Next
    targetTable.Resize targetTable.Range.Resize(targetTable.Range.Rows.Count + rowsToAdd) 
End Sub
```

I could then assign buttons using

```
Public Sub InsertRowsInTable1()
    InsertRowsInTable "Table1"
End Sub
```

This let me add rows to my table and then shift everything down so the tables didnt run into each other.

Thanks everyone again for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways, the easy way or the hard way!

```
' easy way
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To rowsToAdd
    targetTable.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
Next i

' hard way
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = targetTable.ListRows(targetTable.ListRows.Count).Range.Resize(rowsToAdd).Offset(1, 0)
rng.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Answer (score 0):

### Add Rows to Excel Table

**A Quick Fix**

```
Private Sub InsertRowsInTable(ByVal targetTableName As String)
    
    ' Ask user how many rows to ask
    Dim RowsToAdd As Variant
    RowsToAdd = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add?", "Insert Rows", 1)
    
    ' If user didn't input anything, default to 1
    If RowsToAdd = vbNullString Then RowsToAdd = 1
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = Range(targetTableName).ListObject
    
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = tbl.Range
    Dim trCount As Long: trCount = trg.Rows.Count
    Dim rMax As Long: rMax = trg.Worksheet.Rows.Count - trCount - trg.Row + 1
    If RowsToAdd > rMax Then Exit Sub
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = trg.Resize(RowsToAdd).Offset(trCount)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim CouldNotAdd As Boolean
    On Error GoTo CouldNotAddError
    irg.Insert xlDown
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not CouldNotAdd Then
        tbl.Resize trg.Resize(trCount + RowsToAdd)
    End If
            
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            
    Exit Sub

CouldNotAddError:
    CouldNotAdd = True
    Resume Next
        
End Sub
```

**Using `Resize`**

- This uses the more flexible `Application.InputBox` and covers the various issues more extensively.

```vb
Sub AddRowsToTable()
    
    Const Title As String = "Insert Rows"
    Const msgNoRange As String = "Select a range."
    Const msgNoTable As String = "Select a range in a table."
    Const aiPrompt As String = "How many rows would you like to add?"
    Const aiDefault As Long = 1
    Const msgCanceled As String = "Canceled."
    Const msgOnlyDigits As String = "Only digits are allowed."
    Const msgZero As String = "No rows added (0)."
    
    ' Range (Selection)
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox msgNoRange, vbCritical, Title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Selection
    
    ' Table
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = srg.ListObject
    If tbl Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox msgNoTable, vbCritical, Title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Application InputBox
    Dim RowsToAdd As Variant
    RowsToAdd = Application.InputBox(aiPrompt, Title, aiDefault, , , , , 1)
    Debug.Print TypeName(RowsToAdd), VarType(RowsToAdd)
    
    ' Canceled
    If VarType(RowsToAdd) = vbBoolean Then
    'If RowsToAdd = False Then ' this will include 0
        MsgBox msgCanceled, vbExclamation, Title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Only Digits
    Dim rtaString As String: rtaString = CStr(RowsToAdd)
    Dim rtaLen As Long: rtaLen = Len(rtaString)
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To rtaLen
        If Not Mid(rtaString, n, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next n
    If n <= rtaLen Then
        MsgBox msgOnlyDigits, vbCritical, Title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Zero
    If RowsToAdd = 0 Then
        MsgBox msgZero, vbCritical, Title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = tbl.Range
    Dim trCount As Long: trCount = trg.Rows.Count
    Dim rMax As Long
    rMax = trg.Worksheet.Rows.Count - trCount - trg.Row + 1
    If RowsToAdd > rMax Then
        MsgBox "Not enough rows (worksheet)." & vbLf _
            & "Use a number between 1 and " & rMax & ".", vbCritical, Title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = trg.Resize(RowsToAdd).Offset(trCount)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim CouldNotAdd As Boolean
    On Error GoTo CouldNotAddError
    irg.Insert xlDown
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If CouldNotAdd Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "Not enough rows (there is data below).", vbCritical, Title
    Else
        tbl.Resize trg.Resize(trCount + RowsToAdd)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        If RowsToAdd = 1 Then
            MsgBox "Added one row to table '" _
                & tbl.Name & "'.", vbInformation, Title
        Else
            MsgBox "Added " & RowsToAdd & " rows to table '" _
                & tbl.Name & "'.", vbInformation, Title
        End If
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
    
CouldNotAddError:
    CouldNotAdd = True
    Resume Next

End Sub
```

**Using `ListRows`**

- This is my initial attempt, but it is too slow. I abandoned the idea so not all issues are covered (like in the above superior solution).

```vb
Sub AddRowsToTableSlow()
    
    Const Title As String = "Insert Rows"
    Const msgNoRange As String = "Select a range."
    Const msgNoTable As String = "Select a range in a table."
    Const aiPrompt As String = "How many rows would you like to add?"
    Const aiDefault As Long = 1
    Const msgCanceled As String = "Canceled."
    Const msgOnlyDigits As String = "Only digits are allowed."
    Const msgZero As String = "No rows added."
    Const aiMax As Long = 1000
    
    ' Range (Selection)
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox msgNoRange, vbCritical, Title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Selection
    
    ' Table
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = srg.ListObject
    If tbl Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox msgNoTable, vbCritical, Title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Application InputBox
    Dim RowsToAdd As Variant
    RowsToAdd = Application.InputBox(aiPrompt, Title, aiDefault, , , , , 1)
    Debug.Print TypeName(RowsToAdd), VarType(RowsToAdd)
    
    ' Canceled
    If VarType(RowsToAdd) = vbBoolean Then
    'If RowsToAdd = False Then ' this will include 0
        MsgBox msgCanceled, vbExclamation, Title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Only Digits
    Dim rtaString As String: rtaString = CStr(RowsToAdd)
    Dim rtaLen As Long: rtaLen = Len(rtaString)
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To rtaLen
        If Not Mid(rtaString, n, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next n
    If n <= rtaLen Then
        MsgBox msgOnlyDigits, vbCritical, Title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Zero
    If RowsToAdd = 0 Then
        MsgBox msgZero, vbCritical, Title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Max
    If RowsToAdd > aiMax Then
        Dim msgMax As String
        msgMax = "It will take a while adding so many rows." & vbLf _
            & "Are you sure you want to add " & RowsToAdd & " rows?"
        Dim msg As Variant
        msg = MsgBox(msgMax, vbYesNo + vbExclamation, Title)
        If vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim CouldNotAdd As Boolean
    On Error GoTo CouldNotAddError
    For n = 1 To RowsToAdd
        tbl.ListRows.Add
        If CouldNotAdd Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next n
    On Error GoTo 0
    n = n - 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If CouldNotAdd Then
        Select Case n
        Case 0
            MsgBox "No rows added.", vbExclamation, Title
        Case 1
            MsgBox "Only one row was added to table '" _
                & tbl.Name, vbExclamation, Title
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Only " & n & " rows were added to the table '" _
                & tbl.Name & "'.", vbExclamation, Title
        End Select
    Else
        If RowsToAdd = 1 Then
            MsgBox "Added one row to table '" & tbl.Name & "'.", _
                vbInformation, Title
        Else
            MsgBox "Added " & RowsToAdd & " rows to table '" _
                & tbl.Name & "'.", vbInformation, Title
        End If
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
    
CouldNotAddError:
    CouldNotAdd = True
    Resume Next

End Sub
```